# Replace or Remove existing value in Accessibility EditText Node in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility

i want to past a text in **Accessibility node** freshly. i used below line to paste a text in Accessibility edit text node.

```
    hintNameSrc.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
```

what it does is, it adds the clipboard value to Accessibility node not replacing the existing value in the Accessibility node. i want to replace the existing Accessibility node value with **clipboard value** or i need to clear the Accessibility Edit text node value.

Example: 
Assume hint node already having some text like = "**password_hint**" & i am going paste the clipboard value to hint node. Assume clipboard value= "true".

After paste : hint node value = "password_hint**true**"
what i need is, hint node value: "**true**"

What **action** i need to used **replace** or **clear** the Accessibility Edit text node value.  Can you pleas help me in that.

Comment: Can anyone tell something about above description?